# Export Internet Explorer tab to HTML file

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have this code that identifies the active tab

```
Sub Test()
Dim ieTab       As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim shWin       As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim s           As String

Set shWin = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

For Each ieTab In shWin
    s = ieTab.LocationURL
    If s = "my criteria string" Then
        'MsgBox "Page Found", 64
        'Here I need to export the active tab to HTML file
    Else
        'Do Nothing
    End If
Next ieTab

Set ieTab = Nothing
Set shWin = Nothing
End Sub
```

I need to know how to export this active tab to HTML file 
Thanks advanced for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the IF statement I used these lines that solved the problem

```
        f = FreeFile()
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\LocalHTML.html" For Output As #f
    Print #f, ieTab.document.body.innerHTML
    Close #f
```

There's a new problem which is the unicode characters when read using another code @QHarr ,I didn't get correct results
How can I use ADODB to write to the exported html?

I tried this part and the same problem too

```
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myFile = fso.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\LocalHTML.html", False, True)    'Unicode=True
myFile.WriteLine ieTab.document.body.innerHTML
myFile.Close
```

Last Working Solution
This is the code that enables me to export to HTML in right way

```
        Set fStream = New ADODB.Stream
    With fStream
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText ieTab.document.body.innerHTML
        .SaveToFile Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\LocalHTML.html", 2
        .Close
    End With
```

Comment: How can I check my answer as the final answer?

Comment: What link ? I didn't get links yet

Comment: Yes this was for the CSS Query question !! Thanks a lot for the link

Comment: OK I did .. Thanks a lot